# DropDown Positioning absolute element outside of the relative parent container

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm using ReactJs and Emotion, but I know the problem is related to my CSS

I have a Header structure
main (
sidebar
content
)

That's why I'm having trouble positioning an `<ul>` tag correctly with position absolute and this error happens:
**problem gif:**

[image]

I know it is related to the position: relative of my components or my page structure I already tried everything and I couldn't solve it
basically i need my `<ul>` dropdown to be next to my sidebar like this:

[image]

**My JSX:**

```
const Tags = () => {
  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState(SideBarTags);

  const showHideDropItem = tag => {
    setMenuItems(items =>
      items.map(item => ({
        ...item,
        Active:
          item.Name === tag.Name ? (tag.Active === true ? false : true) : false
      }))
    );
  };

  return (
    <SideBar.MenuList>
      {menuItems.map((item, index) => (
        <SideBar.ListItem>
          <SideBar.ListWrap>
            <a>
              <item.Icon size={24} />
              <span className="li-name">{item.Name}</span>
            </a>
          </SideBar.ListWrap>
          {item.DropdownItems && (
            <SideBar.ClosedStyled>
              {item.DropdownItems.map(item => (
                <li className="li-closed" key={item.Name}>
                  <FaGhost size={18} />
                  <a onClick={() => console.log(item.Name)}>{item.Name}</a>
                </li>
              ))}
            </SideBar.ClosedStyled>
          )}
        </SideBar.ListItem>
      ))}
    </SideBar.MenuList>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Global.Container>
      <Header.NavBar>
        <Header.LogoSide>
          <img src={Logo} alt="elo Ghost" />
        </Header.LogoSide>
        <div style={{ width: "100%", background: "#eee" }} />
      </Header.NavBar>
      <Global.Main>
        <SideBar.SideBodyWrap>
          <SideBar.DashMenu>
            <Tags />
          </SideBar.DashMenu>
        </SideBar.SideBodyWrap>
        <Content>a</Content>
      </Global.Main>
    </Global.Container>
  );
}
```

my **CSS** in Js:

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled/macro";
import { shade } from "polished";
import { css } from "@emotion/core";
// Global Containers
const Container = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
`;

const Main = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100% - 55px);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
`;
// Global Containers
export const Global = {
  Container,
  Main
};
// header Nav
export const NavBar = styled.div`
  height: 55px;
  background: #3c8dbc;
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
`;

export const LogoSide = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #3c8dbc;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  height: 55px;
  img {
    height: 35px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
  }
`;
// header Nav
export const Header = {
  NavBar,
  LogoSide
};
// SideBar
const SideBodyWrap = styled.nav`
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #009688;
  background: #3c8dbc;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
`;

const MenuList = styled.ul`
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
`;

export const ListItem = styled.li`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
`;

export const ListWrap = styled.div`
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
  display: flex;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    svg {
      margin-right: 15px;
      transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
    }
  }
  & .icon-li {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  & .down-up_svg,
  .li-name {
    display: none;
  }
`;
export const ClosedStyled = styled.ul`
  ${ListItem}:hover & {
    max-width: 400px !important;
    max-height: 400px !important;
  }
  max-height: 0px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 70%;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: ${shade(0.4, "#3c8dbc")};
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  & .li-closed {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    :hover > svg {
      color: orange;
    }
    svg {
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
  }
  a {
    font-family: "Ubuntu";
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #8aa4af;
  }
`;

const DashMenu = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;

export const SideBar = {
  SideBodyWrap,
  DashMenu,
  ClosedStyled,
  ListItem,
  ListWrap,
  MenuList
};
// SideBar

export const Content = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
`;
```

**example:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-hamilton-oy47v?file=/src/App.js

and :

https://oy47v.csb.app/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're wanting to achieve correctly, I was able to do it by removing `overflow-y:auto` from `.sidebodywrap` and changing `left:70%` to `left:100%` in `.closedstyled`